# Winners of Special Weekly Topic Contest: March 13 - April 3, 2012 (Pies, Cakes, Cookies!)

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, site-promotion

I'm going to be on vacation March 18 - 28, and without internet access for much of that time - which overlaps with what would be three separate weekly contests.

In order to keep these running, questions coming in, and all of you eligible for prizes, I'm changing the contest slightly for the next three weeks.

From March 13 until April 3, the "weekly" topic contest incorporates pies, cakes AND cookies!

### UPDATE: Congratulations to jontyc, rumtscho, and village - winners of the pies, cakes, and cookies contest!

**How to enter:** Ask a question relating to these three topics, and tag it accordingly (use the [pies](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pies), [cake](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cake), or [cookies](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cookies) tag). Each question you ask will get you one entry into a random drawing to win a book (or books) of your choice (under $50). There will be one winner selected from eligible questions in each tag, but each person may only win once during this special 3-week contest. (So, **3 winners total** for this special edition contest.)

**Dates:** The pies, cakes, and cookies contest goes from now (Tuesday 3/13/2012) until 10 AM EDT on Tuesday 4/3/2012.

**Fine Print:** This contest is open to all users across the globe, but the book of the winner's choice must be available for purchase online so that Stack Exchange can easily buy and ship it. The book does not have to be related to the topic of that week, but it should be related to cooking. Questions must remain open and not have a negative score in order to be eligible. You must include at least one of the designated tags for the current contest, but you may add additional tags as necessary. Each person may only win one weekly topic contest in an 8-week period.

To suggest future topics, view past topics and winners, or for more information, please visit the [main topic of the week thread](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1296/6808). On April 3, I will post winners of the pies, cakes, and cookies segment both here and on the main thread.

Comment: Is this in honor of Pi day?

Comment: @hobodave Partly. :)

Comment: What kind of pie should we make for 3/14/15 at 1:59am/pm?

Comment: @makerofthings7- You mean at 3/14/15 9:26?

Comment: Woohoo, that made my morning!

Comment: @jontyc I sent you an email yesterday to the address you used to register on Stack Exchange. If you didn't get it, please email me for details about collecting your prize (my email address is in my profile).